# Why should I tap twice on tableview cell to navigate to another view in iOS, objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app there is a table view with custom cell.in that cell there are (image view, views and labels).data loads succuessfully to the table.
Then what I wanted to display another view(detail view) when user tap on the cell.
I did it by (ctrl+drag) cell and connect it with the detail(second) view.
and selected the segue `kind` as `Show`.so then,when I click on a cell first time it correcly and  and then I have to tap twice to load the detail view. I tried with changing `kind` to `show Detail`, `present Modally`, etc.but the no successful result. Then I tried with using navigation controller within these views.but didn't get any successful result.no idea what to do.I added some code and if you guys want more code I can provide.hope your help.thanx

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  FlightRoundtripDetails *setDetails = [RoundItineraryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 


   resultCell.firstdepatairiportCodeLabel.text = setDetails.FirstDepartureAirport;
        resultCell.firstarriairportCodeLabel.text = setDetails.FirstArrivalAirport;
        resultCell.firststopoverLabel.text = setDetails.Outbound;
}
```

data display correcly.only the issue is when tap a cell.hope your help.thanx.

Comment: add implementation of didselect

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `prepareForSegue:`?

Comment: I didn't implement anything in didSelect.I just only drag the `cell` to `detail view`

Answer (score 0):

I think u have set the tableview selection as Multiple. So goto Attributes Inspector and change the selection to Single.

[image: Attribute screenshot]